# Default Dataset not found, if APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID is set

Tags: apify

Apify documentation [enter link description here](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/dataset) explains, that the default dataset can be named, by setting the environment variable APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID. If I do so, with code sample 1 (see below) before puppeteer-crawler is created and if I crawl a page and store the result with code sample 2, I get a [Dataset-not-found-exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwxWB.png).

What is wrong with my code?
Cheers Wulfgäääng

// Code Sample 1: Setting default dataset id

```
process.env.APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID = datasetName;
```

const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
...

// Code Sample 2: Storing result

```
log.info(`APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID: ${process.env.APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID}`);
const _env = Apify.getEnv();
log.info(`Apify.getEnv().defaultDatasetId:  ${_env.defaultDatasetId}`);
try{
    await Apify.pushData(_result);
} catch(err){
    console.log(`Error pushData: ${err.message}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right the code will work on your local environment but not on Apify platform.

You need to set up ID/name of an existing dataset on Apify platform to APIFY_DEFAULT_DATASET_ID.
If you want to create or use named dataset in your actor code I recommend using [Apify.openDataset()](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/apify#apifyopendataset-datasetidorname-options-promise-dataset-dataset) function. It will use or create a dataset for your actor run. There is an example:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const namedDataset = await Apify.openDataset('my-dataset-name');
    console.dir(namedDataset);
    await namedDataset.pushData({test:"foo bar"});
});
```

It will work locally the same as on the platform.